# How to move .entitlements files for HealthKit in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, healthkit, entitlements

Do you know how to move .entitlements files for HealthKit connectivity?

In this giant project there are multiple build-targets, which means I have about 6 of those, in an already crowded base folder, and I'd like them to be somewhere else.

But As soon as I move them from the base folder they stop working, and I can't find a place to re-link them, nor can I find any information elswhere.

What am I missing here? :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! You can move them, and then the location has to be updated in the Build Settings :)